# Should I use Traefik's GZIP compression or the server's?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gzip, traefik

In general, and specifically in the case of Spring Boot Web (the original, not the reactive one, version 2.5.4), can I expect better performance/compression from the server's own native gzip compression option or from Traefik's middleware?

I'd assume the server's, but I'd rather not assume at all, and Traefik's page on the subject ([here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/compress/)) doesn't seem to give any warning like "try to enable GZIP compression in your server's framework before enabling this middleware".

Comment: What are your criteria? Latency? Cpu load? Memory consumption? In any case you should measure your self to validate any suggestions.

Comment: CPU load is most important. I'd just try to benchmark it myself, but I'm not quite sure how to perform this kind of benchmark without having the decompression on the side making the request affecting things.